# JavaFX 2.0 how do i get my GUI builder? Which was in old JavaFX available?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, javafx, javafx-2

JavaFX 2.0 GUI builder is removed for Linux? Like in old JavaFX we had that available. But now in latest 2.0 i do not have any more GUI is that correct?

[image]

Follow up: installed plugin

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gui builder for JavaFX 2.0 is called `SceneBuilder`.

**Update:** SceneBuilder can be downloaded here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html

Comment: Edited above. I installed that plugin. But i think its not available yet right?

Comment: Judging by description this plugin is going to run SceneBuider as external app. But SceneBuilder is not available yet so it seems that this plugin do nothing until SceneBuilder release.